# Проверка наличия группы ID в таблице SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, select, pgsql

Есть массив id ('1','2','88','3'...)
Нужно проверить, что все эти id есть в таблице (SQL запрос),
Если каких-то нет, вернуть не достающие в запросе.
Например если в БД нет, '1' и '88', вернуть нужно их
Как сделать такую проверку одним запросом, что бы не слать на каждый id запрос?

БД pgsql

Comment: Преобразовать массив в набор записей (например, с помощью UNNEST) и NOT EXISTS либо LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался UNNEST

Answer (score 0):

Есть множество решений. Мне лично наиболее очевидным кажется
использование оператора `EXCEPT`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (88)) AS t_2
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM t_1
;
```